# Working with binomial coefficient $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom nk=0$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm sure there's an identity or some known "trick" to solve this but I couldn't find it (Looked in Wikipedia, Wolfram and here):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k} =0
$$

I want to know how this can be proven. I tried induction but I'm not sure what to do with ${{n+1}\choose k}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the binomial theorem: $0=(1-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}$.

Comment: @SirJMP not **detailed-detailed** but a hint\heading...

Comment: @SirJMP I understand it, it's newton's binomial theorem. but I'm not sure how to prove it...

Comment: actually, nevermind... It's no problem finding proof for the theorem... X(

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that this is true for $n>0$. (For $n=0$, the sum is equal to $0^0=1$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\matrix{n\\k}\right)x^ky^{n-k}
$$
set $x=-1$ and $y=1$